# How do I create a function that takes the column means of a subset of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, data-analysis

Using this simpler dataframe below as an example, I was trying to take the mean for columns B and C for A = "hi" and for B = "bye."

```
A <- c("hi", "bye", "hi", "hi", "bye")
B <- c(1, 2, 1, 9, 4)
C <- c(2, 5, 6, 1, 4)

HiBye.df <- data.frame(A, B, C)


A      B      C
hi     1      2
bye    2      5
hi     1      6
hi     9      1
bye    4      4
```

I able to successfully do this for one row at a time, using the following code:

```
HiMeans <- subset(HiBye.df, A == "hi")
HiMeans <- colMeans(HiMeans[ ,c(2:3)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, there are many different levels of the factor of column A in the dataset I am using, so I'd like to be able to vectorize it. I tried the following code to create a function to do this for each factor x:

```
means <- function (x){
  subsetx <- subset(HiBye.df, A == "x")
  meanx <- colMeans(subsetx[ ,c(2:3)])
  meanx
}

HiMeans
       B        C 
3.666667 3.000000
```

However, I then was returned with this:

```
means(hi)

      B   C 
    NaN NaN
```

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: `dplyr::summarize(HiBye.df, across(B:C, mean), .by = A)`

Comment: The answers other people have given are good, but the specific reason your function didn't work is because of where you put quotation marks: the first line should be `subsetx <- subset(HiBye.df, A == x)` (not `A=="x"`), and you should call it with your variable in quotes, as `means("hi")`. When I do this, I get the expected results.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh its more code typing it out that way though

Comment: Sure I just thought OP should know specifically why their code didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `dplyr`. Group by your factor variable and then `summarise` across the columns you want to get the mean for.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- c("hi", "bye", "hi", "hi", "bye")
B <- c(1, 2, 1, 9, 4)
C <- c(2, 5, 6, 1, 4)

HiBye.df <- data.frame(A, B, C)

HiBye.df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c("B","C"), .fns = mean), .names = "{.col}_mean"))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  A     B_mean C_mean
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 bye     3       4.5
2 hi      3.67    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(.~A, HiBye.df, mean)
    A        B   C
1 bye 3.000000 4.5
2  hi 3.666667 3.0
```

Comment: aggregate does have `subset` parameter: `aggregate(.~A, HiBye.df, mean, subset = A=='hi')` Though I do not think OP wants to subset the data but rather find the mean per group. So you do not need to subset the data

Comment: @Onyambu yes, you are right, I don't need to subset the data. Thanks!